# Failed to verify bitcode in TNSMLKitCamera.framework/TNSMLKitCamera

Tags: ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I am experiencing this issue that causes `tns run ios` to fail when building on a real device. Using the emulator works fine but whenever I try to run or build on a real device, the changes cannnot be applied and the error is `error: exportArchive: Failed to verify bitcode in TNSMLKitCamera.framework/TNSMLKitCamera: error: Bundle only contains bitcode-marker /var/folders/5d/_v1mn0f16w7dt6k7dbvby_c00000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.neH/Root/Payload/mobile.app/Frameworks/TNSMLKitCamera.framework/TNSMLKitCamera (armv7)`

Any help/guidance is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you using any plugins in your app? Did you try a clean build?

Comment: Yes, I have tried a clean build (even removed the iOS platform). I am using a number of plugins but the plugin with the TNSMLKitCamera wrapper is the nativescript-firebase-plugin.

Comment: Are you actually using MLKit? If you are not using, remove it from your app (You may set the value of `ml_kit` to `false` in the `firebase.nativescript.json` file).

Comment: I am not using MLKit. It's not in the `firebase.nativescript.json`. I added and set it to false just to be sure but the error still persists. Thanks

Comment: As far I know that is the only plugin uses MLKit. Try running a clean build, if error still persists, please share the sample project where the issue can be seen.